# ProgressDialog is not getting displayed when i invoke a AsyncTask which returns values

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android app, i have an activity which displays 'ExpandableListView'. The values are retrieved from an API(AsyncTask). But due to network latency, i wanted to show ProgressDialog during retrieving these values. But that dialog is not at all displayed. Can someone help me?

Following is my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how i am calling an AsyncTask

```
GetSubTopicData objSubTopics=new GetSubTopicData(Learning_Activity.this);
listChildTopics=objSubTopics.execute(getMainTopicURL).get();
processChildData(listChildTopics,index);
```

Here is how I designed my AsyncTask:
When I click on MainTopic(Menu Item, I need to get sub-menu items by invoking this below AsyncTask. I wanted to have a ProgressDialog here, till i get these childmenu items. So please help me here.

```
public class GetSubTopicData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<String>>
{
    String strResponse;
    private Context mContext=null;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog=null;

    public GetSubTopicData(Context context)
    {
        mContext=context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
        mDialog.setTitle("Fetching Data");
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> s) {
        //super.onPostExecute(s);
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String strSubTopicURL=params[0];
        List<String> strSTopics=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            //creating a URL
            URL url = new URL(strSubTopicURL);

            //Opening the URL using HttpURLConnection
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //StringBuilder object to read the string from the service
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //We will use a buffered reader to read the string from service
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            //A simple string to read values from each line
            String json;

            //reading until we don't find null
            while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                //appending it to string builder
                sb.append(json + "\n");
            }

            //finally returning the read string
            strResponse= sb.toString().trim();
            con.getInputStream().close();
            con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(strResponse);
            JSONObject jo=null;
            //listDataHeader=new String[ja.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                strSTopics.add(jo.getString("SubTopicName"));
                //strClsSubjectNames[i]=jo.getString("SubjectName");
                Log.d("SubTopicName",jo.getString("SubTopicName"));

            }
            Log.d("SubTopicName",""+strSTopics.size());

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strSTopics;
    }
}
```

Find screenshot here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using `get()` when calling AsyncTask, which executes the code in the current thread (!!!) instead of another thread. Also, it won't call `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`.

If you want to run the code on another thread, use `execute()` instead. Then you can process the data in `onPostExecute()`. However, remember to cancel the AsyncTask when you leave the activity, and call `isCancelled()` inside `doInBackground()` often (in the while loop for instance), so that you can return early if the task is cancelled.

Comment: Thanks for responding, as i mentioned this class has to return list of strings(as i will call this class multiple times from multiple places). So i need to use get() to receive the values from the class. I tried having the same above class in the activity class and this list<String> as global var and tried to assign values in doInBackground, and invoked like objSubTopics.execute(getMainTopicURL), but still didnt get the ProgressDialog. Can you please any pointers where we use AsyncTask with return values? Looking forward your help.

Comment: You can't use AsyncTasks with return value (unless you call get(), which defeats the whole point of using an AsyncTask). You can try passing a listener in the constructor of the AsyncTask and call this listener in onPostExecute.

Comment: Does anybody have any other inputs please help me.